# Fazer post em duas tabelas simultaneamente em AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

o código abaixo ele está funcionando, porém a minha dúvida é a seguinte: Existe alguma forma de fazer um post em dois endereços diferentes simultaneamente utilizando esse mesmo código sem repeti-lo?

Por exemplo, no código abaixo eu faço a inserção dos dados em uma tabela, porém existem outros campos da minha página que vão para outra tabela. Nessa situação existe algum artifício que possa ser feito nesse mesmo código ou eu teria que repeti-lo e inserir os dados da outra tabela?

```
$.ajax({  

        url:'http://localhost:8080/teste/rest/cadastro',  
        type:'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data :  dados,      
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) { 

            }  
    });
```

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Uma dúvida, os outros campos, que vão para outra tabela, algum destes dados depende do outro post?

Comment: Sim, depende desse primeiro post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível utilizar mais de uma url na mesma requisição. Como alternativa, você pode utilizar uma função para enviar a requisição à partir de uma url fornecida, assim não repetindo o código.

Exemplo:

```
    function sendMyAjax(URL_address){
       $.ajax({  
            url: URL_address,  
            type:'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data :  dados,      
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) { 

                }  
        }); 
    };

sendMyAjax('http://localhost:8080/teste/rest/cadastro');
sendMyAjax('http://localhost:8080/teste2/rest/cadastro2');
```

Fonte: [Multiple url in same ajax call?is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097747/multiple-url-in-same-ajax-callis-this-possible)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!